# selenium - cannot receive the li element under the ul

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, html-lists

I've read all the posts related here and in google and none helped me with my issue,
im trying to read with selenium the li element from a website, i basically need all the li childs in lists.

the code i wrote in java:

```
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(ByTagName.tagName("form"));
    element1 = elements.get(0).findElement(ByTagName.tagName("iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(element1);
    element2 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Scroller']//ul"));
    childs = element2.findElements(ByTagName.tagName("div"));

    driver.close();
```

and the returned value for childs is empty for some reason.
can anyone help me please?
ive tried xpath, css selector and tagnames, nothing helped.

Comment: Unless we see the html, its not possible; However, try to replace "ByTagName.tagName" with "By.tagName".

Comment: Make sure you are into iframe

Comment: This code doesn't reference a single `li` element, so what do you think would happen?

Comment: thank you all for answering, i have tried to attach the HTML picture but i dont have enough reputations yet, anyway i have only one ul, and under it many li tags, in each li tag i have many divs - which are my interest. the ul element returened correctly, but when i try to reach its childs - the li, its empty, in this code ive posted, i tried to reach the div elements under the li hoping this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to see your HTML picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvVzW.png

A little tip, just copy/paste the HTML into your question, that works much better and you don't need any reputation for it.

Anyway, if all you are doing is trying to grab the `div`'s under each `li`, you can do this using a CSS selector:

```
div#Scroller > ul > li > div
```

If not, show us *what* `div`'s you mean to get.

Comment: thanks, unfortunatly, it returned the nosuchelementexception:
Oct 30, 2013 12:14:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFO: Bad input type: "email", creating a text input
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node was not an HTML element
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'

Comment: @Er85, could you please post the full HTML? I also noticed you are using the HTMLUnit driver. That's fine but I am wondering whether it's actually 'seeing' the elements correctly. Could you please use something like the ChromeDriver to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: done Arran, if i may,there is another weird issue partially related to my question above which im still trying to figure out..i managed to get the li, but there is a list of 719 li and when page loads i manage to receive only 107 li to my web element list. i tried to use the wait option on the web driver but it doesnt seem like its related to page load timing issue, any idea how to handle such a thing?

Comment: @Er85, I'd post a new question: you'll have more chance of others answering too, that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and read all the li items as an array in a loop.

```
//div[@id="Scroller"]/ul[0]/li



//div[@id="Scroller"]/ul[0]/li[1]
```

Comment: didn't work unfortunatly, it throws an exception: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //div[@id='Scroller']/ul[0]/li[1]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Er85, 

Your going to need to post what exactly the html is for anyone to help you.

Comment: I couldn't since this page required a log in password and username of my work, but the issue solved already, many thanks for your help.